# Table footnotes without footnote marks

Tags: tables, footnotes, parnotes

In my table I would like to use footnotes for more detailed description. Therefore I'm currently using `\parnotes`. Unfortunately `\parnotes` also creates footnote marks which I don't want to have.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

How can I remove these footnote marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but reading http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/parnotes, perhaps

```
\renewcommand{\parnotemarkfmt}[1]{}
```

will work.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a footnote you don't have to use one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{Bewertung des Erscheinungsbilds}
 \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
  \toprule
   Vergleichsaspekt  & CSS3 & SVG  & Canvas & Beschreibung \\
  \midrule
   Anzeige im Chrome & o.E. & o.E. & o.E.   & bla \\
  \bottomrule
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\footnotesize o.E. = ohne Einschränkungen}
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the \footnote command with the optional argument as [0].  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\newlength\tablewidth
\def\blob{%
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
  \hline
  Title & Column 1 & Column 2\\
  \hline
  First Test & 1.234 & 5.389\footnote[0]{\scriptsize This is the
   footnote text blah blah blah blahty blah}\\
  \hline
  Second Test & 3.894 & 1.586~~\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}
\settowidth{\tablewidth}{\blob}

  \begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Caption goes here}
  \centering\begin{minipage}{\tablewidth}   % USE CALCULATED MINIPAGE WIDTH
  \renewcommand\footnoterule{}%    % ELIMINATE LITTLE LINE SEPARATER
  \blob%
  \vspace{-2ex}%                    % SHIFT FOOTNOTE UP
  \end{minipage}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: EDITED to explicitly use the traditional `table` floating environment.